# Mysql multiple COUNT and join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have table "tree".

I have query: `SELECT * FROM`tree`WHERE`pid`=10`
This query returns 10 items.

I want to get something like that in result:

```
id | pid | title | subElements
11 | 10  | t 1   | 12
12 | 10  | t 2   | 16
13 | 10  | t 3   | 0
...
```

How too build join query to count sub items for this 10 items?

Comment: It is not possible in one query

Comment: Ok, but how much queries I need to do to get count of sub elements for this 10 items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.pid, t1.title , count(t2) as subElements FROM tree as t1 
LEFT JOIN tree as t2 ON t2.pid = t1.id
WHERE t1.pid=10
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.pid, t1.title
```

Comment: It is a tree structure with unknown depth

Comment: I tried it on one of my tables (changed INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN) and it worked. My table also has unknown depth of pid

Comment: and how this query is supposed to perform recursive traverse down the tree? PS: I don't even mention that `WHERE` is on a wrong place and that `COUNT(t2)` would cause error

Comment: sorry about the WHERE... my bad.
About the recursive part: sorry... didnt get that part of the question right because i thought it had to do with direct children. Looked like @Mirgorod only needed those.